# How to build ARToolKit For Android libARWrapper.so

Tags: artoolkit

Through the terminal I compile android directory of the build. Sh file, the following problems

```
./build.sh: line 100: /ndk-build: No such file or directory
./build.sh: line 106: /ndk-build: No such file or directory
```

Please help me, really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

here you can find all the information on how to setup your environment to run the build:
http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=4_Android:android_native

I guess your environment variables are not set. See section
'Building Native Android Libraries'